# MongoDb $regex falla al momento de buscar numeros

Tags: regex, mongodb

Tengo una colección users que tiene esta estructura

```
{
  name: 'Eric',
  account: 13310
},
{
  name: 'Ivan',
  account: 12120
}
```

Esta es la sentencia que estoy usando

```
db.users.find( "account": { $regex: /13/, $options: 'i' } );
```

Pero me regresa un error

```
Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "$regex has to be a string",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue"
}
```

Como puedo hacer la consulta? Quiero encontrar todo lo que contenga en cualquier posición el número "13" en el índice account. Leí que se deben usar sólo strings pero no puedo parsear los documentos por que son más de 100k.

Estoy buscando algo así

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ACCOUNT LIKE '%13%'
```

Comment: Porque no usas: db.users.find({"account": /13/}); o db.users.find({"account": { $regex: /13/, $options: 'i' }} );

Comment: No funciona como sugeriste. No regresa nada.

Comment: Como te quedo con mi cambio?????

Comment: No regresa nada, de plano se salta la línea el shell de Mongo.

Comment: Revisa ya te puse una respuesta que probe en el shell yo mismo, el problema con los anteriores comentarios es que solo matchean cuando el campo es string puedes probarlo despues si quieres

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
db.users.find({$where: "/13/i.test(this.account)"});
```

Puedes revisar este link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908100/mongodb-regex-search-on-integer-value